# Which is the difference between $P(A \mid B)$ and $P(A=t \mid B)$ in a Bayesian Network?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, bayesian

Which is the difference between $P(A \mid B)$ and $P(A=t \mid B)$ in a Bayesian Network, where $A$ and $B$ are boolean values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say that the difference is merely that the first one denotes a probability mass function and the latter denotes just a probability, that is a value. For instance

$$
P(A|B)=\begin{cases} 1/3 \mbox{ if A is true}\\ 2/3 \mbox{ if A is false}\end{cases}
$$
and hence
$$P(A=t | B)=1/3.$$

It does not appear to have anything to do with Bayesian theory.

Comment: Thanks! Thus in a calculus, P(A=t|B) does not really make sense. For example in $\sum\nolimits_{L}  \sum\nolimits_{A}  \sum\nolimits_{F}  $ = P(T) * P(F) * P(S=t|F) * P(A|T,F)* P(L|A)* P(R=t|L)

Comment: If $A$ and $B$ are both random variables, to reason about $P(A=t | B)$, you have to fix $B = b$. For example $P(A | B=b)$ could represent a probability mass function, and $P(A=t|B=b)$ is probability that $A$ being $t$ conditioned on a specific value of $B$.